# Elastic Search search query for nested array

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "application": {
        "package_name": "com.jackhenry.OregonFirstCU",
         "countries": [
            {
                "short_name": "US"
            }
         ]
},
"application": {
    "package_name": "com.jackhenry.OregonFirstCU",
    "countries": [
        {
            "short_name": "US"
        }
    ]
},
"application": {
        "package_name": "com.jackhenry.OregonFirstCU",
        "countries": [

        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get results for both empty array and US for `application.countries` and `application.countries.short_name`

Comment: The below query giving the results related to US only {
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "should": [
    {
     "term": {
      "application.countries.short_name": "US"
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 },
 "_source": "application"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you want to fetch results which either contain **US** or do not contain any country name. You can apply `should` between `term` and not `exists`

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                 "exists": {
                    "field": "application.countries.short_name"
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "application.countries.short_name": [
                 "US"
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Richa for the help, it really gave me an idea how to frame search query in ES.